# C# unit test for POST method that uses DB context with inMemoryDb

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, mocking

Im using a InMemoryDatabase
for doing some Post 's and Gets for my react app. I just started writing unit tests but one particulat one(Post_Id_WorkEntry_shouldReturn_Ok) is giving me a hard time because I get thrown an error of this type: `The instance of entity type ' Project ' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {' Id '} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using ' DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging ' to see the conflicting key values.`

My controller:

```
    namespace Timelogger.Api.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class ProjectsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ApiContext _context;

        public ProjectsController(ApiContext context)
        {
            _context = context;

        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("HelloWorld")]
        public string HelloWorld()
        {
            return "Hello Back!";
        }


        // GET api/projects
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Get() //async
        {
            return Ok(_context.Projects.Include(x => x.WorkEntries));
    
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] Project prj)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    Project newProject = new Project(prj.Name, prj.StartDate, prj.EndDate);
                    switch(newProject.ValidateProject())
                    {
                        case ProjectStatus.INVALID_DATE:
                            return BadRequest("Invalid dates");

                        case ProjectStatus.SUCCES:
                            _context.Projects.Add(newProject);
                            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                            return Ok("Added new project with ID=" + prj.Id);
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    return BadRequest(e.Message);
                }
            }
            return BadRequest("Invalid json format");
        }

        //[HttpPut("{id}")]
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("{Id:int}/WorkEntry")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Post(int id, [FromBody] WorkEntry workEntry)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    Console.Write("WorkEntry====: " + workEntry.ToString());
                    var updatedProject = _context.Projects.AsNoTracking().Include(x => x.WorkEntries).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
                    switch (updatedProject.ValdidateAndMergeWorkEntry(workEntry))
                    {
                        case ValidStatus.SUCCES_NEW_WORKENTRY_ADDED:
                            Console.WriteLine("SUCCES_NEW_WORKENTRY_ADDED");
                            _context.Projects.Update(updatedProject);
                            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                            return Ok("Work entry added for project with ID=" + updatedProject.Id);

                        case ValidStatus.SUCCES_HOURS_MERGED:
                            Console.WriteLine("SUCCES_HOURS_MERGED");
                            _context.Projects.Update(updatedProject);
                            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                            return Ok("Work entry merged for project with ID=" + updatedProject.Id);

                        case ValidStatus.INVALID_HOURS_ALREADY_BOOKED:
                            Console.WriteLine("ERROR_HOURS_ALREADY_BOOKED");
                            return BadRequest("Hours are already over the legal meeting");

                        case ValidStatus.INVALID_DAY:
                            Console.WriteLine("INVALID_DAY");
                            return BadRequest("Day is not valid");

                        case ValidStatus.INVALID_HOURS:
                            Console.WriteLine("INVALID_HOURS");
                            return BadRequest("Hours are not valid");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                    return BadRequest(e.Message);
                }
            }
            return BadRequest("Invalid json format");
        }

    }
}
```

And this is are my UT

```
    namespace Timelogger.Api.Tests
    {
    public class ProjectsControllerTests
    {
        ProjectsSeedDataFixture psdf = null;

        [SetUp]
        public void Init()
        {
            psdf = new ProjectsSeedDataFixture();
        }

        [TearDown]
        public void CleanUp()
        {
            psdf.ProjectsContext.Database.EnsureDeleted();
        }

        [Test]
        public void HelloWorld_ShouldReply_HelloBack()
        {
            //arrange
            ProjectsController sut = new ProjectsController(psdf.ProjectsContext);

            //act
            var actual = sut.HelloWorld();

            //assert
            Assert.AreEqual("Hello Back!", actual);
        }

        [Test]
        public void Get_shouldReturn_Ok()
        {
            //arrange
            ProjectsController sut = new ProjectsController(psdf.ProjectsContext);
            var testProject1 = new Project("e-conomic Interview", new System.DateTime(2019, 12, 1), new System.DateTime(2020, 12, 10));
            Stubs.PopulateWorkEntries(testProject1);
            psdf.ProjectsContext.Projects.Add(testProject1);
            psdf.ProjectsContext.SaveChanges();

            //act
            var actual = sut.Get();
            var okResult = actual as OkObjectResult;

            //assert
            Assert.IsNotNull(okResult);
            Assert.AreEqual(200, okResult.StatusCode);
        }

        [Test]
        public void Post_shouldReturn_Ok()
        {
            //arrange
            ProjectsController sut = new ProjectsController(psdf.ProjectsContext);
            var testProject1 = new Project("e-conomic Interview", new System.DateTime(2019, 12, 1), new System.DateTime(2020, 12, 10));
            Stubs.PopulateWorkEntries(testProject1);

            //act
            var actual = sut.Post(testProject1);
            var okResult = actual.Result as OkObjectResult;

            //assert
            Assert.IsNotNull(okResult);
            Assert.AreEqual(200, okResult.StatusCode);
            //Assert.AreEqual("Added new project with ID=1", okResult.Value);
 
        }

        [Test]
        public void Post_shouldReturn_BadRequest()
        {
            //arrange
            ProjectsController sut = new ProjectsController(psdf.ProjectsContext);
            var testProject1 = new Project("e-conomic Interview", new System.DateTime(2020, 12, 10), new System.DateTime(2019, 12, 1));
            Stubs.PopulateWorkEntries(testProject1);

            //act
            var actual = sut.Post(testProject1);
            var badRequestResult = actual.Result as BadRequestObjectResult;

            //assert
            Assert.IsNotNull(badRequestResult);
            Assert.AreEqual(400, badRequestResult.StatusCode);
            Assert.AreEqual("Invalid dates", badRequestResult.Value);
        }

        [Test]
        public void Post_Id_WorkEntry_shouldReturn_Ok()
        {
            //arrange
            ProjectsController sut = new ProjectsController(psdf.ProjectsContext);
            psdf.ProjectsContext.Database.EnsureDeleted();
            var project = new Project("e-conomic Interview", new System.DateTime(2019, 12, 1), new System.DateTime(2020, 12, 10));
            psdf.ProjectsContext.Projects.Add(project);
            psdf.ProjectsContext.SaveChanges();
            WorkEntry workEntry = new WorkEntry { id = project.WorkEntries.Count + 1, Day = new System.DateTime(2019, 12, 1), Hours = 3 };

            //act
            var actual = sut.Post(1 , workEntry);
            var okResult = actual.Result as OkObjectResult;

            //assert
            Assert.IsNotNull(okResult);
            Assert.AreEqual(200, okResult.StatusCode);
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea how I can make the post testable? It's because the context from the post is different then the one from UT ? is there a possibility to mock it ?

Update:

This is how my test class looks right now

```
    using Timelogger.Api.Controllers;
using NUnit.Framework;
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Timelogger.Entities;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace Timelogger.Api.Tests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class ProjectsControllerTests
    {
        private static DbContextOptions<ApiContext> CreateNewContextOptions()
        {
            // Create a fresh service provider, and therefore a fresh 
            // InMemory database instance.
            var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
                .AddEntityFrameworkInMemoryDatabase()
                .BuildServiceProvider();

            // Create a new options instance telling the context to use an
            // InMemory database and the new service provider.
            var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApiContext>().UseInMemoryDatabase("data").UseInternalServiceProvider(serviceProvider);
            
            return builder.Options;
        }

        [Test]
        public void HelloWorld_ShouldReply_HelloBack()
        {
            using (var context = new ApiContext(CreateNewContextOptions()))
            {
                //arrange
                ProjectsController sut = new ProjectsController(context);

                //act
                var actual = sut.HelloWorld();

                //assert
                Assert.AreEqual("Hello Back!", actual);
            };
        }

        [Test]
        public void Get_shouldReturn_Ok()
        {
            using (var context = new ApiContext(CreateNewContextOptions()))
            {
                //arrange
                ProjectsController sut = new ProjectsController(context);
                var testProject1 = new Project("e-conomic Interview", new System.DateTime(2019, 12, 1), new System.DateTime(2020, 12, 10));
                Stubs.PopulateWorkEntries(testProject1);
                context.Projects.Add(testProject1);
                context.SaveChanges();

                //act
                var actual = sut.Get();
                var okResult = actual as OkObjectResult;

                //assert
                Assert.IsNotNull(okResult);
                Assert.AreEqual(200, okResult.StatusCode);
            };
        }

        [Test]
        public void Post_shouldReturn_Ok()
        {
            using(var context = new ApiContext(CreateNewContextOptions()))
            {
                //arrange
                ProjectsController sut = new ProjectsController(context);
                var testProject1 = new Project("e-conomic Interview", new System.DateTime(2019, 12, 1), new System.DateTime(2020, 12, 10));
                Stubs.PopulateWorkEntries(testProject1);

                //act
                var actual = sut.Post(testProject1);
                var okResult = actual.Result as OkObjectResult;

                //assert
                Assert.IsNotNull(okResult);
                Assert.AreEqual(200, okResult.StatusCode);
                Assert.AreEqual("Added new project with ID=1", okResult.Value);
            };
 
        }

        [Test]
        public void Post_shouldReturn_BadRequest()
        {
            using (var context = new ApiContext(CreateNewContextOptions()))
            {
                //arrange
                ProjectsController sut = new ProjectsController(context);
                var testProject1 = new Project("e-conomic Interview", new System.DateTime(2020, 12, 10), new System.DateTime(2019, 12, 1));
                Stubs.PopulateWorkEntries(testProject1);

                //act
                var actual = sut.Post(testProject1);
                var badRequestResult = actual.Result as BadRequestObjectResult;

                //assert
                Assert.IsNotNull(badRequestResult);
                Assert.AreEqual(400, badRequestResult.StatusCode);
                Assert.AreEqual("Invalid dates", badRequestResult.Value);
            };
        }

        [Test]
        public void PostIdWorkEntry_shouldReturn_Ok()
        {
            using (var context = new ApiContext(CreateNewContextOptions()))
            {
                //arrange
                ProjectsController sut = new ProjectsController(context);
                var project = new Project("e-conomic Interview", new System.DateTime(2019, 12, 1), new System.DateTime(2020, 12, 10));
                context.Projects.Add(project);
                context.SaveChanges();
                WorkEntry workEntry = new WorkEntry(new System.DateTime(2019, 12, 3), 3 );

                //act
                var actual = sut.Post(project.Id, workEntry);
                var okResult = actual.Result as OkObjectResult;

                //assert
                Assert.IsNotNull(okResult);
                Assert.AreEqual(200, okResult.StatusCode);
            };
        }

        [Test]
        public void PostIdWorkEntry_shouldReturn_BadRequestInvalidHoursSurpassed()
        {
            using (var context = new ApiContext(CreateNewContextOptions()))
            {
                //arrange
                ProjectsController sut = new ProjectsController(context);
                var project = new Project("e-conomic Interview", new System.DateTime(2019, 12, 1), new System.DateTime(2020, 12, 10));
                WorkEntry workEntry1 = new WorkEntry { id = project.WorkEntries.Count + 1, Day = new System.DateTime(2019, 12, 1), Hours = 7 };
                project.WorkEntries.Add(workEntry1);
                context.Projects.Add(project);
                context.SaveChanges();
                WorkEntry workEntry2 = new WorkEntry { id = project.WorkEntries.Count + 1, Day = new System.DateTime(2019, 12, 1), Hours = 2 };

                //act
                var actual = sut.Post(project.Id, workEntry2);
                var badRequestResult = actual.Result as BadRequestObjectResult;

                //assert
                Assert.IsNotNull(badRequestResult);
                Assert.AreEqual(400, badRequestResult.StatusCode);
                Assert.AreEqual("Hours are over the legal point", badRequestResult.Value);
            };
        }


        [Test]
        public  void PostIdWorkEntry_shouldReturn_BadRequestInvalidDay()
        {
            using (var context = new ApiContext(CreateNewContextOptions()))
            {
                //arrange
                ProjectsController sut = new ProjectsController(context);
                var project = new Project("e-conomic Interview", new System.DateTime(2019, 12, 1), new System.DateTime(2020, 12, 10));
                context.Projects.Add(project);
                context.SaveChanges();
                WorkEntry workEntry = new WorkEntry { id = project.WorkEntries.Count + 1, Day = new System.DateTime(2020, 12, 11), Hours = 2 };

                //act
                var actual = sut.Post(project.Id, workEntry);
                var badRequestResult = actual.Result as BadRequestObjectResult;

                //assert
                Assert.IsNotNull(badRequestResult);
                Assert.AreEqual(400, badRequestResult.StatusCode);
                Assert.AreEqual("Day is not valid", badRequestResult.Value);
            };
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the EF context is tracking the project you added in the test method, then when your controller retrieves it from the database because of the AsNoTracking it doesn't see it's the same project it's tracking.

You could try using two different contexts, that way the context you pass to your controller won't be tracking the project.

This is how I'm using the in memory database for testing:

```
var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApiContext>()
                .UseLazyLoadingProxies(fixture.IsLazyLoading)
                .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
                .Options;
                
Seedcontext = new ApiContext(options);
Context = new ApiContext(options);
Resultcontext = new ApiContext(options);

Seedcontext.Database.EnsureCreated();

Initializer.Seed(Seedcontext);
```

Each context gets access to the same DB but tracking is confined to each separate context.

Comment: using your inputs i got to pass my initial problem, but now it seems that there is a problem with the update or delete. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: Attempted to update or delete an entity that does not exist in the store. this is the exception. The thing is that with the debugger i see that object updatedProject getting a updated, but it crashes while doing SaveChanges

Comment: Because you dropped the database with the ensuredeleted call. This deletes the database so no tables exist anymore to update. Try removing that line from your test. What were you trying to accomplish with it?

Comment: ..also if your database was seeded you don’t need to add a project. You just want to test adding the workentry right?

Comment: it was a leftover but in the current code, i dont do any ensuredeleted call and the behaviour stays the same. I will post below an updated version of my code.

Comment: What if you remove the asnotracking from the controller?

Comment: removed it before hand. No effect. Im starting to thing that maybe there is some contradiction within my db. I have a <Project> db which has id, name,some dates, and a WorkEntry type array. This array also has a id, a day and and int called hours. Could this some how generate a problem?

Comment: Can you update your post with how your code looks like now, and add your orojectseeddatafixture?

Comment: What does your controller look like now? You’re not seeding the Db right?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure the table ID is added automatically
(Auto-increment allows a unique number to be generated automatically when a new record is inserted into a table)

Answer (score 0):

The best would be to dispose the context and register it again.

But try to call

```
_context.ChangeTracker.Clear();
```

also if you are not using `Sqlite` that [does not support](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/26707) this, you can call

```
_context.EnsureDeleted()
_context.EnsureCreated()
```